# Flutter integration test running twice on web

Tags: flutter, webdriver, flutter-web, flutter-test, flutterdriver

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/102250)

Setup:

1. Clone [repository](https://github.com/garrettApproachableGeek/integration_tests_duplicated)
2. Run `chromedriver --port=4444` in another terminal
3. Run `flutter drive --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart --target=integration_test/example_test.dart -d chrome`

It seems like the test is running twice as there are two documents inserted into Firestore where there should only be one document inserted.

This behavior is only happening on web, it doesn't produce the same behavior on iOS

If you clone the repo and test it for yourself please change the collection name of `examples` to something else to not clash with other testers

Code for when the repository is removed

```
void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final now = DateTime.now();
  const String collectionName = 'examples';
  String currentMinute = DateFormat.yMd().add_jm().format(now);

  documentsInsertedThisMinute() async {
    var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collectionName);
    var snapshots =
        await collection.where('foobar', isEqualTo: currentMinute).get();
    return snapshots.size;
  }

  setUpAll(() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
  });

  testWidgets(
    'Single document created',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
      int preExistingDocuments = await documentsInsertedThisMinute();
      print('Pre-existing documents: $preExistingDocuments');

      await tester.pumpWidget(const MyApp());

      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(collectionName)
          .doc()
          .set({'foobar': currentMinute});

      int documentsAfterSingleInsert = await documentsInsertedThisMinute();
      expect(documentsAfterSingleInsert, 1);
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues with running the code twice when using `-d chrome` with or without `--headless` flag.

What I use:

**Multiline Linux**

```
flutter drive \
--driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart \
--target=integration_test/sec_rules_test.dart \
--device-id web-server \
--dart-define=PROJECT_ID=someProjectId
```

**Multiline Windows (Powershell)**

```
flutter drive `
--driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart `
--target=integration_test/example_test.dart `
--device-id web-server `
--dart-define=PROJECT_ID=someProjectId
```

Also documented [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction#5b-web), of course it doesn't specify if you run it in `-d chrome` it will behave as such.